# Add subview to self.view but let certain subviews content not be covered by the added subview

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I want to add a subview to self.view that covers the whole area (like a dimming view). But underneath it there are some views that I don't want to be affected by the added subview (I don't want those views to have a dimmed effect). Is this possible to do?

I know there is an "easy" solution to it; to move those subviews that I don't want to be affected to the front (over the added subview) but that has unwanted effects for me so I can't use that solution.

I'm targeting iOS 8 and above.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this subview?

Comment: So, just to be clear, you cannot change the z-positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look into creating a [CALayer mask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/mask) to subtract the subviews frames below from your view's layer above.

```
var path = UIBezierPath(rect: topView.frame)

var subviewPath1 = UIBezierPath(rect: subview1.frame)
var subviewPath2 = UIBezierPath(rect: subview2.frame)
path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
path.appendPath(subviewPath1)
path.appendPath(subviewPath2)

var maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

topView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Comment: That's the solution I was thinking about myself. Cheers!